Importing keycloak SPI in a docker volume
I create a docker compose file that aims to launch postgres, keycloak and pgadmin... So far so good.
Here is my docker compose:
version: "3.8"
name: keycloak-env
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "postgres", "-U", "root" ]
      timeout: 45s
      interval: 10s
      retries: 10
    # networks:
    #   - postgres-network
    expose:
      - '5432'
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgres/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - local

  pgAdmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    container_name: pgAdmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: root@root.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
    # networks:
    #   - postgres-network
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgres/pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    links:
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - local
      
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0.4
    container_name: keycloak
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8180:8080'
    environment:
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_SCHEMA: public
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: root
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: root
      KC_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: false
      KC_LOG_LEVEL: info
      KC_METRICS_ENABLED: true
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: root
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: root
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    # networks:
    #   - postgres-network
    command: 
      - start-dev
    volumes:
      - ./data/keycloak/import:/opt/keycloak/data/import
      - ./data/keycloak/providers:/opt/keycloak/providers
    networks:
      - local

# networks:
#   postgres-network:
networks:
      local:
          driver: bridge

Now here is my issue:

I have a user webservice that is on my local machine and runs on port 8099 ...
I implemented a user storage SPI that i want to add to my keycloak.

that's why i added a volume that contains my providers : ./data/keycloak/providers:/opt/keycloak/providers
I added the jar in this folder and I was able to get the provider when getting to user federation ...
the provider was correcly enabled



When trying to login, I access the login page, which was expected. If i use a valid login and password, I have an error message.

Section 16: Keycloak Remote User Authentication. User Storage SPI.
In my logs i have the following message:
2024-05-25 01:27:13 2024-05-24 23:27:13,303 WARN  [com.company.keycloak.UsersApiLegacyService] (executor-thread-1) Error fetching user test2@test.com from external service: No content to map due to end-of-input
2024-05-25 01:27:13  at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 1]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
2024-05-25 01:27:13  at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 1]
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4990)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4892)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3846)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3814)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at org.keycloak.util.JsonSerialization.readValue(JsonSerialization.java:75)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at org.keycloak.broker.provider.util.SimpleHttp.asJson(SimpleHttp.java:210)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at com.company.keycloak.UsersApiLegacyService.getUserByUserName(UsersApiLegacyService.java:24)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at com.company.keycloak.RemoteUserStorageProvider.getUserByUsername(RemoteUserStorageProvider.java:87)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageManager.lambda$getUserByUsername$19(UserStorageManager.java:389)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at org.keycloak.utils.ServicesUtils.lambda$timeBoundOne$1(ServicesUtils.java:83)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$RefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:400)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:528)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageManager.getUserByUsername(UserStorageManager.java:389)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserCacheSession.getUserByUsername(UserCacheSession.java:271)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.findUserByNameOrEmail(KeycloakModelUtils.java:247)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.AbstractUsernameFormAuthenticator.getUserFromForm(AbstractUsernameFormAuthenticator.java:189)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.AbstractUsernameFormAuthenticator.getUser(AbstractUsernameFormAuthenticator.java:168)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.AbstractUsernameFormAuthenticator.validateUserAndPassword(AbstractUsernameFormAuthenticator.java:149)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.UsernamePasswordForm.validateForm(UsernamePasswordForm.java:55)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.UsernamePasswordForm.action(UsernamePasswordForm.java:48)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processAction(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:151)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticationAction(AuthenticationProcessor.java:1011)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.processFlow(LoginActionsService.java:365)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.processAuthentication(LoginActionsService.java:336)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.authenticate(LoginActionsService.java:328)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.authenticateForm(LoginActionsService.java:393)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService$quarkusrestinvoker$authenticateForm_32b8e198ac3110abd1d5774e83a4cf87858129f4.invoke(Unknown Source)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler.handle(InvocationHandler.java:29)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:141)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:147)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:582)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
2024-05-25 01:27:13     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
2024-05-25 01:27:13 
2024-05-25 01:27:13 2024-05-24 23:27:13,902 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-1) type="LOGIN_ERROR", realmId="4af46e5c-d13d-40d5-874a-24289b993625", clientId="apps-ws-code-flow-client", userId="null", ipAddress="172.23.0.1", error="user_not_found", auth_method="openid-connect", auth_type="code", redirect_uri="http://localhost:8083/callback", code_id="77083824-39ef-4537-b73b-9e0f0d0520c8", username="test2@test.com"

On the other side, I have breaking points on my web service and none is triggered by the call ... Apparently the user web service is not triggered.
In the SPI Jar, i set the URL to my machine IP address.
